# TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined
    at postName (http://127.0.0.1:9000/scripts/controllers/main.js:28:12)
    at Scope.$scope.submit (http://127.0.0.1:9000/scripts/controllers/main.js:10:7)
    at http://127.0.0.1:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10348:21
    at http://127.0.0.1:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:18333:17
    at Scope.$eval (http://127.0.0.1:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12175:28)
    at Scope.$apply (http://127.0.0.1:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12273:23)
    at Scope.$delegate.__proto__.$apply (<anonymous>:855:30)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:18332:21)
    at HTMLFormElement.jQuery.event.dispatch (http://127.0.0.1:9000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:4641:9)
    at HTMLFormElement.elemData.handle (http://127.0.0.1:9000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:4309:46) angular.js:9563(anonymous function) angular.js:9563(anonymous function) angular.js:7004Scope.$apply angular.js:12275$delegate.__proto__.$apply VM1976:855(anonymous function) angular.js:18332jQuery.event.dispatch jquery.js:4641elemData.handle
```

My main.js file:

'use strict';

```
angular.module('sayHiApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {

    // Accepts form input
    $scope.submit = function() {

      // POSTS data to webservice
      postName($scope.input);

      // GET data from webservice
      var name = getName();

      // DEBUG: Construct greeting
      $scope.greeting = 'Sup ' + name + ' !';

    };

    function postName ($scope, $http, dataToPost) {

      $http.post('/name', dataToPost).
      success(function(data) {
        $scope.error = false;
        $scope.data = data;
      }).
      error(function(data) {
        $scope.error = true;
        $scope.data = data;
      });
    }

    // GET name from webservice
    function getName ($scope, $http) {

      $http.get('/name').
      success(function(data) {
        $scope.error = false;
        $scope.data = data;

        return data;
      }).
      error(function(data) {
        $scope.error = true;
        $scope.data = data;

        return 'error name';
      });

    }

  });
```

I'm not sure what this error is referring to? If it's referring to the 'post' method on '$http' then I'm very confused.. Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: Are you passing the $http parameter to the function at all?

Comment: Ahh man.. Yep that's the issue. Sucks being new to this. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is referring to the 'post' method on '$http' as you suggested.

You need to add $http as a parameter in the controller function so angular will inject it (just as you did with $scope).

I did another change to your code, removed the $scope and $http parameters from the inner functions as they are known in the function because of closure.

```
angular.module('sayHiApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

// Accepts form input
$scope.submit = function() {

  // POSTS data to webservice
  postName($scope.input);

  // GET data from webservice
  var name = getName();

  // DEBUG: Construct greeting
  $scope.greeting = 'Sup ' + name + ' !';

};

function postName (dataToPost) {

  $http.post('/name', dataToPost).
  success(function(data) {
    $scope.error = false;
    $scope.data = data;
  }).
  error(function(data) {
    $scope.error = true;
    $scope.data = data;
  });
}

// GET name from webservice
function getName () {

  $http.get('/name').
  success(function(data) {
    $scope.error = false;
    $scope.data = data;

    return data;
  }).
  error(function(data) {
    $scope.error = true;
    $scope.data = data;

    return 'error name';
  });
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

the function `postName` doesn't need to have these vars passed to it 
`$scope, $http` it only needs the `dataToPost` the other two vars are already accessible. Your function should just look like this

```
function postName (dataToPost) {

  $http.post('/name', dataToPost).
  success(function(data) {
    $scope.error = false;
    $scope.data = data;
  }).
  error(function(data) {
    $scope.error = true;
    $scope.data = data;
  });
}
```